# Clear multiple textboxes present inside a groupbox which is inside a panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
    Public Sub ClearTextBoxes(ByVal Frm As Form)
     Dim Ctl As Control
     For Each Ctl In Frm.Controls
        If TypeOf Ctl Is TextBox Then Ctl.Text = ""
        If TypeOf Ctl Is GroupBox Then
            Dim Ctl1 As Control
            For Each Ctl1 In Ctl.Controls
                If TypeOf Ctl1 Is TextBox Then
                    Ctl1.Text = ""
                End If
            Next
        End If
        Next
      End Sub
```

I have this method, but the problem is, my groupboxes are present inside a panel, just confused a lot by these controls.

Comment: `inside a groupbox which is inside a panel`  Your code seems to ignore the panel.

Comment: Oh, I see, but I'm lil new, don't know how can I loop with the panel. Can you help me with the code ? Thanks :)

Comment: You loop it the same way you're already doing it, just need to add a check for a Panel first, then search panel controls for a groupbox, then search groupbox controls for textboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
   Public Sub ClearTextBoxes(ByVal Frm As Form)
      Dim Ctl As Control

      For Each Ctl In Frm.Controls
         If TypeOf Ctl Is TextBox Then Ctl.Text = ""

         If TypeOf Ctl Is Panel Then
            Dim Ctl1 As Control

            For Each Ctl1 In Ctl.Controls
               If TypeOf Ctl1 Is TextBox Then Ctl1.Text = ""

               If TypeOf Ctl1 Is GroupBox Then
                  Dim Ctl2 As Control

                  For Each Ctl2 In Ctl1.Controls
                     If TypeOf Ctl2 Is TextBox Then Ctl2.Text = ""
                  Next
               End If
            Next
         End If
      Next
   End Sub
```

It may not cover all scenarios but it will work for what you have told us.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way is to just filter the controls in the enumerations:

```
For Each p As Panel In Frm.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
  For Each gb As GroupBox In p.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()
    For Each tb As TextBox In gb.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
      tb.Clear()
    Next
  Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your suggestions, I have concluded that this code works perfect for me.

```
    Public Sub ClearTextBoxes(ByVal Frm As Form)
    Dim Ctl As Control

    For Each Ctl In Frm.Controls
        If TypeOf Ctl Is TextBox Then Ctl.Text = ""

        If TypeOf Ctl Is Panel Then
            Dim Ctl1 As Control

            For Each Ctl1 In Ctl.Controls
                If TypeOf Ctl1 Is TextBox Then Ctl1.Text = ""

                If TypeOf Ctl1 Is GroupBox Then
                    Dim Ctl2 As Control

                    For Each Ctl2 In Ctl1.Controls
                        If TypeOf Ctl2 Is TextBox Then Ctl2.Text = ""
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If

        If TypeOf Ctl Is GroupBox Then
            Dim Ctl1 As Control
            For Each Ctl1 In Ctl.Controls
                If TypeOf Ctl1 Is TextBox Then
                    Ctl1.Text = ""
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```